# Use of articles in certain situations

Tags: meaning-in-context, articles, definite-article, zero-article

I read that with certain places, "the" or the zero article can be used, but all depend on context. For example:

- I'm in hospital. (mainly indicates that you had a health problem, so
  you're being checked by a doctor). ACTIVITY-ABSTRACT.
- I'm in the hospital. (mainly indicates that you're just perhaps
  visiting the hospital, the building itself). LOCATION-CONCRETE.

But, what if you were a doctor? Would you say the same?

I think it would be without any article because you are not referring to the building itself. Instead, you refer to the fact that you're doing primary activities inside the hospital where you are.

Would the same logic apply if you were a lawyer? Would you say: I'm in court now?

JUST IN CASE: I know that in NAmE is usually used "the" with "hospital" as a set phrase, but as I'm learning British English, I'd like to know how it would be in the British contexts.

Comment: "In hospital" and "in the hospital" mean the same in British and American English, respectively.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But it's said that there's a difference as many grammar books say. Not just with this word, the same happens with others, such as: school, church and so on.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. A doctor would probably say something like "I'm on duty", but certainly not "I'm in hospital" unless they were a patient. And, yes, a lawyer would say they were 'in court' when the court was in session.